# Pass data from server to HTML page

Tags: html, nodejs-server

I have three pages: server.js, user.js, index.js.
my server takes data from the request header and builds a User object.
the user object has a method that does calculate and save at result.
I want to pass the result to index.js or to an HTML page and manipulate the result.
I try to save the result in a static verb and create obj in the index.page.
but I get Error.
any idea how to do that?

```
    //server.js 

    const User = require('./user.js');
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
        console.log("connecting to server");
        jsonHeader = JSON.stringify(req.headers);
        user = CreateUserObject(req);
        User.setResult(30); }



    // user.js


class User{
    constructor(){
        this.ip=0;
        this.language =' ';
        this.result = "";
    }

    setUserDetails(requestHeader){
        this.Ip = requestHeader.header('x-forwarded-for');
        this.language = requestHeader.header('accept-language');
    }
    setResult(number){
        User.staticResult = number;

    }
    getResult(){
        return User.staticResult;
    }

};
User.staticResult = 15;
module.exports = User;



//index.js
import User from 'user.js';
var user  = new User();
 ................
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is [asking for a solution without attempting to show any work](https://can-i-haz.codes/). Please provide some code to help us work with you to find a solution.

Comment: I don't have some code to show I only want advised how to do that

Comment: Then SO is not the right place for this.

Comment: The server is two line of code, using express nodejs

Comment: @aviv.L — You're using Express? You failed to mention that in the question. It's also covered in the (short) *Guide* on the ExpressJS website, maybe you should start there.

Comment: @ Quentin , I search in the guide but I don't find anything that can help me

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

Comment: @Connum - I edit the question

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is to pass data to the HTML file.

If yes, then this can be solved using the template engine.

**handlebars** is one of them, I find it easy to use

> app.js

```
const handleBars = require('handlebars');
readFile("fileName.html,'utf8').then(
 function(data)
 {
    let template = handleBars.compile(data,{strict:true});
    let replacements = /*assign the value to html file variable enclosed in {{ }}*/
    {
       title : "MyTitle",
       body  : "MyBody"
    }
    let html = template(replacements);
    let fss = require('fs');
    fss.writeFile("test.html", html, function(err) {
    if(err) 
    {
     return console.log(err);
    }
  }
```

> filename.html

```
<div class="entry">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
   <div class="body">
     {{body}}
   </div>
</div>
```

For more information how to use [handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/)